# How to set/Change default $PATH value for all users?

Tags: linux, debian, environment-variables

How to set/change the default **`$PATH`** environment variable to be `$PATH/root` **for all users** at the same time ?

Comment: Hi @najeeb, Welcome to SuperUser. Could you please tell what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You just add a short script  in `/etc/profile.d`:

```
if [ "${PATH#*/your/dir}" = "${PATH}" ]; then                                                    
    export PATH=$PATH:/your/dir                                                                  
fi
```

Comment: /etc/environment is no longer used?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile